# Dragging is very slow with many DOM items on page

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

React DnD doesn't appear to scale well.

I have a list of five hundred drop targets and it take several seconds to pick up an element.

Is there anyway of speeding this up?

The list scrolls perfectly smoothly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using [react-virtual](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized) to reduce the number of DOM elements in existence, although unfortunately the drawing performance is well behind native rendering.

Also, a helpful thread...

https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/issues/421

> While technically you can stretch React DnD performance to ~3000
>   items, there’s no way for it to not lag after a certain point without
>   changing the API (and making it less useful). If you have thousands of
>   rows, I think you should be using virtualized lists anyway.